# Pythonic way of accepting single number or list and use it as a list (equivalent to numpy.atleast_1d() )

Tags: python, list

I have a function which accepts single numbers (e.g. `int` or `float`), but also a `list` like structure. This argument will always be further processed as a `list`.

What would be the pythonic way of converting the single number arguments to a list and let the lists be?

I would have assumed that this works, but it raises a `TypeError`:

```
def foo(a):
    a = list(a)
    a.append(5)
    # and so on
```

I don't want to create a list of a list like this:

```
def foo(a):
    a = [a]
    a.append(5)
    # and so on
```

Comment: It's usually less complexity to accept one type of thing and let the caller worry about conforming to it. In this case, if the caller only has a single int, they can use `foo([i])` to call your function expecting a list…

Comment: `a = [a] if not isinstance(a, list) else a`, but the pythonic way would likely be to only accept 1 type of input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just check if it isn't a list first and make it one if it isn't?

```
def foo(a):
    if not isinstance(a, list):
        a = [a]
    ...
    a.append(5)
```

Comment: Don't use `type() ==`, use `isinstance()`.

Comment: @deceze Duly noted and edited accordingly, thank you

Comment: Yeah, I had hoped not to use `isinstance` or `try`, `except`, but I guess I'll stick to it then.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `isinstance` like

```
if (isinstance(a, list)):
    # Do something
else:
    # Do something
```

You could do `isinstance` for any type, like int.

But a more Pythonic way would probably be

```
try:
    a.append(5)
except TypeError:
    a = [a]
    a.append(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always go with the EAFP model as well (easier to ask for forgiveness than permission) and just use a `try/except`:

```
def foo(a):
    try:
        a.append(5)
    except TypeError:
        a = [a]
        a.append(5)
    print(a)
foo(1)
foo([2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function, but I bet some people here are not going to like it:

```
def func(a):
    return a+[5] if type(a) == type([]) else [a,5]
```

For example:

```
print(func([4]))
print(func(4))
```

Comment: Please see the comments for GreenCloakGuys answer.  You should use `isinstance` as it handles duck typing.